# java.lang.VerifyError: com/adobe/creativesdk/aviary/internal/account/BillingContentFactory

Tags: android, sdk, adobecreativesdk

I am new to adobe creative SDK for android, I have integrated adobe creative SDK with my application successfully. Its running successfully on Android 5.0 and up.
But when tried to run on 4.0, 4.1, 4.4, 4.4.2 and 4.4.4 it gives error like :-

```
java.lang.VerifyError: com/adobe/creativesdk/aviary/internal/account/BillingContentFactory
    at com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.AdobeImageBillingService.<init>(AdobeImageBillingService.java:41)
    at com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.AdobeImageBillingService.getInstance(AdobeImageBillingService.java:220)
    at com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.internal.account.AdobeAccountConnection.<init>(AdobeAccountConnection.java:31)
    at com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.AdobeImageEditorActivityAbstract.createAdobeAccountConnection(AdobeImageEditorActivityAbstract.java:552)
    at com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.AdobeImageEditorActivityAbstract.onCreate(AdobeImageEditorActivityAbstract.java:535)
    at com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.AdobeImageEditorActivity.onCreate(AdobeImageEditorActivity.java:29)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1280)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1096)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help will be great.

Comment: What versions of the Creative SDK dependencies are you using? The latest version of Creative SDK Auth is `0.9.1186` and the latest version of the Image Editor is `4.8.3`. There is a sample dependency configuration on the [Creative SDK Image Editor guide](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/imageediting/index.html#config).

Comment: i am also using a latest versions of both

Answer (score 5):

I am facing the same issue regarding Creative SDK, but I resolved same with the use of multidex. Please below steps for solving this error.

1. Enable Multidex and add gradel support to your app level gradel file

```android
defaultConfig {
 multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

2. Now initialize Multidex at application level

```android
@Override
public void onCreate() {
  MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

This solution works for me, I hope this will help you also.